# roulette (changed rules) skill or luck?

Tags: luck, skill

how would You call the following game, a skill game or a game of luck?

lets take a roulette wheel and change it where there is no green zero field. and instead of 18 black and red numbers we will have 18 red and 17 black numbers.

now we will offer a player vs player game where any of the 2 players is free to chose the 17 black numbers (with disadvantage) or the 18 red numbers (with advantage). could this be a mental skill game? or is it still a game of luck?

Comment: If your game is 'player vs player' it is not roulette, and *vice versa*. Either way, this seems to be asking about mathematics rather than an actual game.

Comment: correct it is not an actual game, because it is not offered this way by anyone. but tomorrow I could offer this game.but IMO it is roulette. in the USA the wheel has 2 zeros and it is called roulette.

Comment: All you are really proposing is the current game of roulette, where you can choose to be the house, or the player. You obviously always choose to be the house.

Comment: there is no house. it is player vs player

Comment: Now I finally see what you mean. No, there is no skill involved. There is no game unless one player chooses black and one red, in which case the red player has the advantage; so any player who can count and think will choose red each time and the game does not even start. In future please put some effort into explaining questions, and please put some effort into thinking about them before asking.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough from the start. roulette is a game where a game is on even both players will go for red or black. in this case no one will lose or win because there is no house. red is always the better option but for example one could chose to go for black after a series of 10 times red. this could be a strategic game of patience and both could always bet red until one loses patience and will bet on black.

Comment: @Caro This is not how playing this sort of game works.  Black will never be the correct choice, even if it comes up sometimes.

Comment: in 35 times Black will come 17 times and red 18 times on the long run. but You are correct that for a mental skilled player black will never be the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am not 100 percent clear about the game you are proposing (especially what happens when both players choose the same colour) clearly this is no skill game. The optimal strategy is to always take red and beating this strategy can only be done with luck.

Comment: in case both players chose same color, no one wins or lose because it is a player vs player game and no house involved. but as no house is involved each player can chose the best chance for winning. so wouldnt it be mental skill what is needed to understand this?

Comment: No rational player would choose black, ever. If your opponent chooses red, the correct answer is "I'm not going to play this game." The only way this becomes a "mental" game is if Player A threatens to beat Player B with a tire iron unless Player B plays black. Then it's just extortion by a different name. Or it can be a "mental" game if Player A fast-talks Player B into playing black. But without coercion, deceit, or idiocy, nobody's going to play black.